# Add background section colors in plotly using shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I created a plot using ggplot where I added background colors at certain regions of the plot:

```
p.ggplot +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin= -Inf, xmax= Inf, ymin= -5, ymax= 0.2),alpha=0.3, fill="#b71e3f") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin= -Inf, xmax= Inf, ymin= 0.8, ymax= 1),alpha=0.3, fill="#1f59b7") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin= -Inf, xmax= Inf, ymin= 0.2, ymax= 0.8),alpha=0.3, fill="#514e4f")
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the background shapes are not conserved when turning the ggplot object into a plotly object through ggplotly:

```
p.plotly <- ggplotly(p.ggplot)
```

[image]

Following the instructions on https://plot.ly/r/shapes/ , I added the following lines to the plotly object, but the output remains the same. Anybody know what I'm missing?

Thank you.

```
p.plotly <- layout(p.plotly,

            shapes = list(
                         list(type = "rect",
                              fillcolor = "#b71e3f", line = list(color = "#b71e3f"), opacity = 0.3,
                              x0 = 0, x1 = 2, xref = "x",
                              y0 = -5, y1 = 0.2, yref = "y"),

                         list(type = "rect",
                               fillcolor = "#1f59b7", line = list(color = "#1f59b7"), opacity = 0.3,
                               x0 = 0, x1 = 2, xref = "x",
                               y0 = 0.2, y1 = 0.8, yref = "y"),

                           list(type = "rect",
                               fillcolor = "#514e4f", line = list(color = "#514e4f"), opacity = 0.3,
                               x0 = 0, x1 = 2, xref = "x",
                               y0 = 0.8, y1 = 1, yref = "y")))

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p.plotly), "sexCheckPlot.html")
```

Comment: It is easier for us to help you if you provide a reproducible example so that we do not have to reconstruct some sample data and guess the code you used to create your plot.